# Xcode 5 Tab Bar Controller Turns Grey

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, tabview

I am trying to add a new view controller to my tab bar controller. When I connect the two the tab bar turns grey inside the tab bar controller and in the view controller. Why is this happening?

Tried to post image but not allowed. Not enough rep.

Kind Regards,
Darin

See photo here:  https://www.flickr.com/photos/75840697@N03/14185056616
See Video here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/75840697@N03/14228399593/in/set-72157644665844556/

Comment: Are you doing this using code? or is this a storyboard/xcode problem?

Comment: I am doing in this in the storyboard. Control dragging from tab bar controller to view controller and choosing viewing controls under relationship segue.

Comment: Could you try to add an image to dropbox and post the link?

Comment: Just added link to flickr.

Comment: Added video to Flickr as well.

Comment: SOLVED. Several weeks back I installed a few Font and Color themes from Githib. I just deleted them, restarted Xcode and now everything is working as normal.